# C# Code to Connect To a Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 On LAN?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I have programmed (VS2010 SP1, C#) an application which uses a Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 Database to store data, now I want to access those data from LAN. Any Help?? (Please Include All Steps In Your Answer Please)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot connect to a SQL Server Compact database over a LAN, it is a singel user, in-process database enigine - use SQL Server (Express) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what kind of support there is since I don't use Compact, just regular, but you could Map a Drive to the location of the file (assuming you have read/write access from the other machine)

```
Server Explorer -> Data Connections -> Right-Click -> Add Connection
Change server to Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5
Locate the file location (Mapped), enter in other information
```

I'm pretty sure Compact wasn't meant to be run from another machine though

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to connect to the database by specifying the source in the connection string:

> Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5;Data
>   **Source=myFolder\myData.sdf;**